# TSQL PIVOT is throwing multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I've created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 with the following syntax:

```
SELECT [Encounter Number], [AdmitDate - CCYYMMDD], [DischargeDate - CCYYMMDD], 
Encounter.LengthOfStay
,pr.[1] as Proc1
,pr.[2] as Proc2
,pr.[3] as Proc3
,pr.[4] as Proc4
,pr.[5] as Proc5
,pr.[6] as Proc6
,pr.[7] as Proc7
,pr.[8] as Proc8
,pr.[9] as Proc9
,pr.[10] as Proc10
,pr.[11] as Proc11
,pr.[12] as Proc12
,pr.[13] as Proc13
,pr.[14] as Proc14
,pr.[15] as Proc15
,pr.[16] as Proc16
,pr.[17] as Proc17
,pr.[18] as Proc18
,pr.[19] as Proc19
,pr.[20] as Proc20
,pr.[21] as Proc21
,pr.[22] as Proc22
,pr.[23] as Proc23
,pr.[24] as Proc24
,pr.[25] as Proc25
,pr.[26] as Proc26
,pr.[27] as Proc27
,pr.[28] as Proc28
,pr.[29] as Proc29
,pr.[30] as Proc30
,pr.[31] as Proc31
,pr.[32] as Proc32
,pr.[33] as Proc33
,pr.[34] as Proc34
,pr.[35] as Proc35
,pr.[36] as Proc36
,pr.[37] as Proc37
,pr.[38] as Proc38
,pr.[39] as Proc39
,pr.[40] as Proc40
,pr.[41] as Proc41
,pr.[42] as Proc42
,pr.[43] as Proc43
,pr.[44] as Proc44
,pr.[45] as Proc45
,pr.[46] as Proc46
,pr.[47] as Proc47
,pr.[48] as Proc48
,pr.[49] as Proc49,
CASE
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('01.25','01.14','01.59') then 'Brain'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '03.09' then 'Spinal Canal'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('06.4','06.81','26.32') then 'Head/Neck'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('32.29','32.39','32.49','32.59') then 'Lungs/Thorax'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('35.12','35.21','35.22','35.23','35.24') then 'Cardiac Valve'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '36.10' then 'CABG'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '00.66' then 'PCI'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('37.33','37.34','37.35','37.36','37.37') then 'Excision Heart 
       Lesion'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '37.94' then 'Implant Auto Cardioversion/Defib System'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('39.52','39.71','39.78') then 'Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('39.50','39.79','39.72','39.74','39.75','39.76','00.62') 
       then 'Other Vascular'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '38.12' then 'Carotid Endarterectomy'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('38.18','39.29') then 'Lower Limb Vascular'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('38.34','38.44','38.45','39.25','39.71') then 'Other Aortic 
       Vascular'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('44.38','44.95','44.67') then 'Other Gastrointestinal'
WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in 
      ('45.71','45.72','45.73','45.74','45.76','45.77','45.78','45.79','45.81','45.82','45.83','45.41',
'45.42','45.43','45.44','45.45','45.46','45.47','45.48','45.49','48.35','48.63') 
      then 'Colorectal'
      END as ProcGrouper
From Encounter 
left outer join DimFactEncounter
on Encounter.EncounterNumber = DimFactEncounter.EncounterNumber
Left Outer JOIN ( SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT [Encounter Number]
        ,[Procedure Code (Enctr)]
        ,Row_Number() OVER ( Partition By [Encounter Number] Order By [Encounter 
                            Number], [Procedure Code (Enctr)] ) AS RowNumber
        FROM EncounterProc) o
PIVOT ( MAX([Procedure Code (Enctr)] ) for RowNumber IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], 
       [8], [9], [10],[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20]                ,[21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]
,[31], [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40]
       ,[41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [48], [49]) ) t ) pr
on Encounter.EncounterNumber = EncounterProc.[Encounter Number]
where [Date of Service] between @StartDate and @EndDate
and Encounter.InOutCode = 'I'
and AdmitSubService <> 'SIG'
and Encounter.HSP# = 1
and Encounter.ActualTotalCharge > 0
and Encounter.Age >= 65
and Encounter.PayorGroup = 'Medicare'
and [ED Flag] is null
and [DischargeDisposition] not in ('MA', 'TA', '7Z')
and EncounterProc.[Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in 
       ('01.25','01.14','01.59','03.09','06.4','06.81','26.32','32.29','32.39','32.49',
'32.59','35.12','35.21','35.22','35.23','35.24','36.10','00.66','37.33','37.34','37.35','37.36',
       '37.37','37.94','39.52','39.71','39.78','39.50','39.79','39.72','39.74','39.75','39.76','00.62',
       '38.12','38.18','39.29','38.34',
'38.44','38.45','39.25','39.71','44.38','44.95','44.67','45.71','45.72','45.73','45.74','45.75',
       '45.76','45.77',
'45.78','45.79','45.81','45.82','45.83','45.41','45.42','45.43','45.44','45.45','45.46','45.47'
       '45.48','45.49',
'48.35','48.63')
```

When I attempt to alter the stored procedure, I receive the following:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_sc_ConRptsSurgery, Line 16
>   The multi-part identifier "EncounterProc.Encounter Number" could not be bound.

What must be done to the above syntax to correct the above error?

UPDATE:  I changed the left outer join to the following:

```
Left Outer JOIN ( SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [Encounter Number]
,[Procedure Code (Enctr)]
,Row_Number() OVER 
( Partition By [Encounter Number] 
Order By [EncounterNumber], [Procedure Code (Enctr)] ) AS RowNumber
FROM EncounterProc) o
PIVOT ( MAX([Procedure Code (Enctr)] ) for RowNumber IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], 
[10],[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20]
,[21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]
,[31], [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40]
,[41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [48], [49]) ) t ) pr
on Encounter.EncounterNumber = pr.[Encounter Number]
```

UPDATE 2:  Here is the structure of the EncounterProc Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EncounterProc](
[COMPANY CODE] [varchar](5) NULL,
[ENCOUNTER NUMBER] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[PROCEDURE CODE (ENCTR)] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
[DATE OF SERVICE] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
[ENCOUNTER PROC SEQUENCE] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[SURGERY FLAG] [varchar](1) NULL,
[ORDERING PHYSICIAN] [varchar](10) NULL,
[SURGEON] [varchar](10) NULL,
[ASSISTING SURGEON(1)] [varchar](10) NULL,
[ASSISTING SURGEON(2)] [varchar](10) NULL,
[SURGERY REASON] [varchar](10) NULL,
[ANESTHESIOLOGIST] [varchar](10) NULL,
[ANESTHESIA TYPE] [varchar](2) NULL,
[PERFUSIONIST] [varchar](10) NULL,
[NURSE ANESTHETIST] [varchar](10) NULL,
[ANESTHESIA START TIME] [varchar](6) NULL,
[ANESTHESIA STOP TIME] [varchar](6) NULL,
[SURGERY START TIME] [varchar](6) NULL,
[SURGERY STOP TIME] [varchar](6) NULL,
[ENTERED OP RM TIME] [varchar](6) NULL,
[LEFT OP RM TIME] [varchar](6) NULL,
[PACU ADMIT TIME] [varchar](6) NULL,
[PACU DISCHARGE TIME] [varchar](6) NULL,
[USER DEFINED 1] [varchar](30) NULL,
[USER DEFINED 2] [varchar](30) NULL,
[USER DEFINED 3] [varchar](30) NULL,
[USER DEFINED 4] [varchar](30) NULL,
[USER DEFINED 5] [varchar](30) NULL,
[USER DEFINED 6] [varchar](30) NULL,
[USER DEFINED 7] [varchar](30) NULL,
[USER DEFINED 8] [varchar](30) NULL,
[USER DEFINED NUMBER 1] [numeric](18, 4) NULL,
[USER DEFINED DATE 1] [varchar](8) NULL,
[PRINCIPLE SECONDARY PROC] [varchar](1) NULL,
[Updated] [datetime] NULL,
       CONSTRAINT [PK_EncounterProc2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
       (
[ENCOUNTER NUMBER] ASC,
[PROCEDURE CODE (ENCTR)] ASC,
[DATE OF SERVICE] ASC,
[ENCOUNTER PROC SEQUENCE] ASC
       )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS    
       = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
       ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Unforutnately, the errors are still persisting including:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_sc_ConRptsSurgery, Line 95
Invalid column name 'EncounterNumber'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_sc_ConRptsSurgery, Line 103
Invalid column name 'Date of Service'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_sc_ConRptsSurgery, Line 103
Invalid column name 'Date of Service'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_sc_ConRptsSurgery, Line 112
Invalid column name 'Procedure Code (ENCTR)'.
```

Why are these column names deemed invalid?

Update 3: 
Not sure why my question was downvoted?
After parsing thrugh the error message, I restructured the stored procedure as follows:

```
SELECT Encounter.EncounterNumber, [AdmitDate - CCYYMMDD], [DischargeDate - CCYYMMDD], 
Encounter.LengthOfStay
,pr.[1] as Proc1
,pr.[2] as Proc2
,pr.[3] as Proc3
,pr.[4] as Proc4
,pr.[5] as Proc5
,pr.[6] as Proc6
,pr.[7] as Proc7
,pr.[8] as Proc8
,pr.[9] as Proc9
,pr.[10] as Proc10
,pr.[11] as Proc11
,pr.[12] as Proc12
,pr.[13] as Proc13
,pr.[14] as Proc14
,pr.[15] as Proc15
,pr.[16] as Proc16
,pr.[17] as Proc17
,pr.[18] as Proc18
,pr.[19] as Proc19
,pr.[20] as Proc20
,pr.[21] as Proc21
,pr.[22] as Proc22
,pr.[23] as Proc23
,pr.[24] as Proc24
,pr.[25] as Proc25
,pr.[26] as Proc26
,pr.[27] as Proc27
,pr.[28] as Proc28
,pr.[29] as Proc29
,pr.[30] as Proc30
,pr.[31] as Proc31
,pr.[32] as Proc32
,pr.[33] as Proc33
,pr.[34] as Proc34
,pr.[35] as Proc35
,pr.[36] as Proc36
,pr.[37] as Proc37
,pr.[38] as Proc38
,pr.[39] as Proc39
,pr.[40] as Proc40
,pr.[41] as Proc41
,pr.[42] as Proc42
,pr.[43] as Proc43
,pr.[44] as Proc44
,pr.[45] as Proc45
,pr.[46] as Proc46
,pr.[47] as Proc47
,pr.[48] as Proc48
,pr.[49] as Proc49,
    CASE
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('01.25','01.14','01.59') then 'Brain'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '03.09' then 'Spinal Canal'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('06.4','06.81','26.32') then 'Head/Neck'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('32.29','32.39','32.49','32.59') then 'Lungs/Thorax'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('35.12','35.21','35.22','35.23','35.24') then 'Cardiac Valve'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '36.10' then 'CABG'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '00.66' then 'PCI'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('37.33','37.34','37.35','37.36','37.37') then 'Excision Heart 
    Lesion'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '37.94' then 'Implant Auto Cardioversion/Defib System'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('39.52','39.71','39.78') then 'Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('39.50','39.79','39.72','39.74','39.75','39.76','00.62') 
    then 'Other Vascular'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '38.12' then 'Carotid Endarterectomy'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('38.18','39.29') then 'Lower Limb Vascular'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('38.34','38.44','38.45','39.25','39.71') then 'Other Aortic 
    Vascular'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('44.38','44.95','44.67') then 'Other Gastrointestinal'
    WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in              
    ('45.71','45.72','45.73','45.74','45.76','45.77','45.78','45.79','45.81','45.82','45.83','45.41',
    '45.42','45.43','45.44','45.45','45.46','45.47','45.48','45.49','48.35','48.63') 
          then 'Colorectal'
  END as ProcGrouper
From Encounter 
left outer join DimFactEncounter
on Encounter.EncounterNumber = DimFactEncounter.EncounterNumber
Left Outer JOIN EncounterProc
on Encounter.EncounterNumber = EncounterProc.[Encounter Number]
Left Outer JOIN 
( 
SELECT [Encounter Number], [DATE OF SERVICE], 
    [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], 
    [19], [20],[21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]
    ,[31], [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40]
    ,[41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [48], [49]
FROM 
(
 SELECT [Encounter Number], [DATE OF SERVICE]
        ,[Procedure Code (Enctr)]
        ,Row_Number() OVER ( Partition By [Encounter Number] Order By [Encounter Number], [Procedure 
 Code (Enctr)] ) AS RowNumber
 FROM EncounterProc
 where  [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in 
 ('01.25','01.14','01.59','03.09','06.4','06.81','26.32','32.29','32.39','32.49',
 '32.59','35.12','35.21','35.22','35.23','35.24','36.10','00.66','37.33','37.34','37.35','37.36',
 '37.37','37.94','39.52','39.71','39.78','39.50','39.79','39.72','39.74','39.75','39.76','00.62',
 '38.12','38.18','39.29','38.34', '38.44','38.45','39.25','39.71','44.38','44.95','44.67','45.71','45.72','45.73','45.74','45.75',
'45.76','45.77', '45.78','45.79','45.81','45.82','45.83','45.41','45.42','45.43','45.44','45.45',
'45.46','45.47','45.48','45.49', '48.35','48.63')
) o
PIVOT 
( 
    MAX([Procedure Code (Enctr)]) 
for RowNumber IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],[11], [12], [13], [14],[15],     
[16], [17], [18], [19], [20],[21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]
,[31], [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40]
,[41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [48], [49]) 
) t 
) pr
on pr.[Encounter Number] = Encounter.EncounterNumber
where pr.[Date of Service] between @StartDate and @EndDate
and Encounter.InOutCode = 'I'
and AdmitSubService <> 'SIG'
and Encounter.HSP# = 1
and Encounter.ActualTotalCharge > 0
and Encounter.Age >= 65
and Encounter.PayorGroup = 'Medicare'
and [ED Flag] is null
and [DischargeDisposition] not in ('MA', 'TA', '7Z')
```

The stored procedure runs error free now.  However, I'm seeing the same encounter number duplicated for however many rows as it has procedures.  If there are 7 procedures, the stored procedure returns 7 rows for this encounter.

How would I modify the updated code above to ensure only one row per encounter is returned by the stored procedure?

Comment: In regards to your last update, instead of continuing to edit this question you should post a new question with the updated issues and code.  I would also advise to include some data from each table.  But when you are working with PIVOT, the data is being grouped if you include too many distinct values in a subquery it could alter the way the data is presented in final result.

Comment: Thanks.  I decided a new question would be best:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282722/how-to-pivot-over-up-to-49-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error is at the end of your PIVOT:

```
) pr
on Encounter.EncounterNumber = EncounterProc.[Encounter Number]
                                  ^-- this should be pr
```

So the code should be:

```
) pr
on Encounter.EncounterNumber = pr.[Encounter Number]
```

Edit, based on your additional errors, it appears that you are not including the `[DATE OF SERVICE]` in your subquery.  Also it doesn't make sense that you have a filter on the outside WHERE clause using the `[Procedure Code (ENCTR)]` because you are using that column in your `max()` on the PIVOT. Based on those guesses your code seems like it should be:

```
SELECT [Encounter Number], [AdmitDate - CCYYMMDD], [DischargeDate - CCYYMMDD], 
    Encounter.LengthOfStay
    ,pr.[1] as Proc1
    ,pr.[2] as Proc2
    ,pr.[3] as Proc3
    ,pr.[4] as Proc4
    ,pr.[5] as Proc5
    ,pr.[6] as Proc6
    ,pr.[7] as Proc7
    ,pr.[8] as Proc8
    ,pr.[9] as Proc9
    ,pr.[10] as Proc10
    ,pr.[11] as Proc11
    ,pr.[12] as Proc12
    ,pr.[13] as Proc13
    ,pr.[14] as Proc14
    ,pr.[15] as Proc15
    ,pr.[16] as Proc16
    ,pr.[17] as Proc17
    ,pr.[18] as Proc18
    ,pr.[19] as Proc19
    ,pr.[20] as Proc20
    ,pr.[21] as Proc21
    ,pr.[22] as Proc22
    ,pr.[23] as Proc23
    ,pr.[24] as Proc24
    ,pr.[25] as Proc25
    ,pr.[26] as Proc26
    ,pr.[27] as Proc27
    ,pr.[28] as Proc28
    ,pr.[29] as Proc29
    ,pr.[30] as Proc30
    ,pr.[31] as Proc31
    ,pr.[32] as Proc32
    ,pr.[33] as Proc33
    ,pr.[34] as Proc34
    ,pr.[35] as Proc35
    ,pr.[36] as Proc36
    ,pr.[37] as Proc37
    ,pr.[38] as Proc38
    ,pr.[39] as Proc39
    ,pr.[40] as Proc40
    ,pr.[41] as Proc41
    ,pr.[42] as Proc42
    ,pr.[43] as Proc43
    ,pr.[44] as Proc44
    ,pr.[45] as Proc45
    ,pr.[46] as Proc46
    ,pr.[47] as Proc47
    ,pr.[48] as Proc48
    ,pr.[49] as Proc49,
    CASE
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('01.25','01.14','01.59') then 'Brain'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '03.09' then 'Spinal Canal'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('06.4','06.81','26.32') then 'Head/Neck'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('32.29','32.39','32.49','32.59') then 'Lungs/Thorax'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('35.12','35.21','35.22','35.23','35.24') then 'Cardiac Valve'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '36.10' then 'CABG'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '00.66' then 'PCI'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('37.33','37.34','37.35','37.36','37.37') then 'Excision Heart 
               Lesion'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '37.94' then 'Implant Auto Cardioversion/Defib System'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('39.52','39.71','39.78') then 'Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('39.50','39.79','39.72','39.74','39.75','39.76','00.62') 
               then 'Other Vascular'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] = '38.12' then 'Carotid Endarterectomy'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('38.18','39.29') then 'Lower Limb Vascular'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('38.34','38.44','38.45','39.25','39.71') then 'Other Aortic 
               Vascular'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in ('44.38','44.95','44.67') then 'Other Gastrointestinal'
        WHEN [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in 
              ('45.71','45.72','45.73','45.74','45.76','45.77','45.78','45.79','45.81','45.82','45.83','45.41',
        '45.42','45.43','45.44','45.45','45.46','45.47','45.48','45.49','48.35','48.63') 
              then 'Colorectal'
      END as ProcGrouper
From Encounter 
left outer join DimFactEncounter
    on Encounter.EncounterNumber = DimFactEncounter.EncounterNumber
Left Outer JOIN 
( 
    SELECT [Encounter Number], [DATE OF SERVICE], 
        [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20]                ,[21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]
                            ,[31], [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40]
                            ,[41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [48], [49]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT [Encounter Number], [DATE OF SERVICE]
            ,[Procedure Code (Enctr)]
            ,Row_Number() OVER ( Partition By [Encounter Number] Order By [Encounter 
                                Number], [Procedure Code (Enctr)] ) AS RowNumber
        FROM EncounterProc
        where  [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] in 
           ('01.25','01.14','01.59','03.09','06.4','06.81','26.32','32.29','32.39','32.49',
                '32.59','35.12','35.21','35.22','35.23','35.24','36.10','00.66','37.33','37.34','37.35','37.36',
                '37.37','37.94','39.52','39.71','39.78','39.50','39.79','39.72','39.74','39.75','39.76','00.62',
                '38.12','38.18','39.29','38.34', '38.44','38.45','39.25','39.71','44.38','44.95','44.67','45.71','45.72','45.73','45.74','45.75',
                '45.76','45.77', '45.78','45.79','45.81','45.82','45.83','45.41','45.42','45.43','45.44','45.45','45.46','45.47'
                '45.48','45.49', '48.35','48.63')
    ) o
    PIVOT 
    ( 
        MAX([Procedure Code (Enctr)]) 
        for RowNumber IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20]                ,[21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]
                            ,[31], [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40]
                            ,[41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [48], [49]) 
    ) t 
) pr
    on Encounter.EncounterNumber = pr.[Encounter Number]
where pr.[Date of Service] between @StartDate and @EndDate
    and Encounter.InOutCode = 'I'
    and AdmitSubService <> 'SIG'
    and Encounter.HSP# = 1
    and Encounter.ActualTotalCharge > 0
    and Encounter.Age >= 65
    and Encounter.PayorGroup = 'Medicare'
    and [ED Flag] is null
    and [DischargeDisposition] not in ('MA', 'TA', '7Z')
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Please see updates including both updated code and new errors.

Comment: @SidC Without seeing your table structures this would be guess work.  Are you sure you are returning those columns in your query?  Can you edit your question with the table structures?

Comment: @SidC See my edit, you have to be sure that the columns in your where clause are included in your subqueries.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  The stored procedure compiles error free.  Just getting multiple records instead of intended one record per encounter.  Also, how would I add the Surgeon field for each procedure?