# How to PIVOT over up to 49 fields?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table that contains procedure data.  There can be up to 49 entries for a given encounter.  I want to output one row for each account and include the procedure, date and provider.  I've tried writing CASE statements to this end:

```
Select DISTINCT [Encounter Number], 
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '1' Then [Procedure Code (Enctr)] 
END as 'Proc1',
Case When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '1' Then [Date of Service]
END as 'SvcDate1',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '1' Then [Surgeon]
END as 'Surgeon1',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '2' Then [Procedure Code (Enctr)] 
END as 'Proc2',
Case When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '2' Then [Date of Service]
END as 'SvcDate2',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '2' Then [Surgeon]
END as 'Surgeon2',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '3' Then [Procedure Code (Enctr)] 
END as 'Proc3',
Case When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '3' Then [Date of Service]
END as 'SvcDate3',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '3' Then [Surgeon]
END as 'Surgeon3',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '4' Then [Procedure Code (Enctr)] 
END as 'Proc4',
Case When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '4' Then [Date of Service]
END as 'SvcDate4',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '4' Then [Surgeon]
END as 'Surgeon4',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '5' Then [Procedure Code (Enctr)] 
END as 'Proc5',
Case When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '5' Then [Date of Service]
END as 'SvcDate5',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '5' Then [Surgeon]
END as 'Surgeon5',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '6' Then [Procedure Code (Enctr)] 
END as 'Proc6',
Case When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '6' Then [Date of Service]
END as 'SvcDate6',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '6' Then [Surgeon]
END as 'Surgeon6',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '7' Then [Procedure Code (Enctr)] 
END as 'Proc7',
Case When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '7' Then [Date of Service]
END as 'SvcDate7',
CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '7' Then [Surgeon]
END as 'Surgeon7'
from EncounterProc
where [Date of Service] between '20090101' and '20091231'
and [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] is not null
Group by [Encounter Number], [Encounter Proc Sequence],[Procedure Code (ENCTR)], [Date of     
Service], Surgeon
```

The query output shows some duplicated rows and the query isn't placing procedure 3 (for example) in the Proc3 column.
How would I setup the PIVOT syntax for this scenario?

UPDATE:
I've read the MSDN Library documentation on PIVOT, and also the link shared in Comments.  I took a stab at adapting those sources to my need as follows:

```
Select [Encounter Number],
[1] as Proc1,
[Date1] as SvcDate1,
[MD1] as MD1,
[2] as Proc2,
[Date2] as SvcDate2,
[MD2] as MD2,
[3] as Proc3,
[Date3] as SvcDate3,
[MD3] as MD3,
[4] as Proc4,
[Date4] as SvcDate4,
[MD4] as MD4
From
(Select * From
(SELECT [Encounter Number]
        ,[Procedure Code (Enctr)]
        ,Row_Number() OVER ( Partition By [Encounter Number] Order By 
                    [Encounter Number], [Procedure Code (Enctr)] ) AS RowNumber
        FROM EncounterProc)
PIVOT ( MAX([Procedure Code (Enctr)] ) for RowNumber IN 
( [1], [Date1], [MD1],[2], [Date2], [MD2], [3], [Date3], [MD3], [4], [Date4],   
      [MD4]))
```

When I run this query, SSMS gives me the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'.
```

Update2:  Based on Stuart's comment, I've revised the query to be:

```
Select [Encounter Number],
p.[1] as Proc1,
p.[Date1] as SvcDate1,
p.[MD1] as MD1,
p.[2] as Proc2,
p.[Date2] as SvcDate2,
p.[MD2] as MD2,
p.[3] as Proc3,
p.[Date3] as SvcDate3,
p.[MD3] as MD3,
p.[4] as Proc4,
p.[Date4] as SvcDate4,
p.[MD4] as MD4
From
(Select * From
(SELECT [Encounter Number]
        ,[Procedure Code (Enctr)] 
        ,[Date of Service]
        ,[Surgeon]
        ,Row_Number() OVER ( Partition By [Encounter Number] Order By   
                     [Encounter Number], [Encounter Proc Sequence] ) AS RowNumber
        FROM EncounterProc) p
PIVOT ( MAX([Procedure Code (Enctr)] ) for RowNumber IN 
( [1], [Date1], [MD1],[2], [Date2], [MD2], [3], [Date3], [MD3], [4], [Date4], 
    [MD4]) )
```

I now receive a new error stating:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

which points to the closing parenthesis of the PIVOT statement.

What must be done to fix the syntax error?

Comment: I believe this example is better served by the CASE ... END syntax than the PIVOT syntax. In order to perform a pivot you would first need to fold the data one more time, which seesm unnecessarily complex.

Comment: When pivoting with `case` and `group by` and without actual data aggregation a `max` or `min` is usually used. See example ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18282959/2523686)).

Comment: you need a table alias for the subquery before the PIVOT command; e.g. SELECT * FROM (SELECT...) p PIVOT ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query is the closest one, except that you did not enclosed every `case` into aggreagate function. Also it seems that you do not need some columns in `group by` clause:

```
select
    [Encounter Number], 
    Proc1 = max(CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '1' Then [Procedure Code (Enctr)] END),
    SvcDate1 = max(Case When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '1' Then [Date of Service] END),
    Surgeon1 = max(CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '1' Then [Surgeon] END),
    Proc2 = max(CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '2' Then [Procedure Code (Enctr)] END),
    SvcDate2 = max(Case When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '2' Then [Date of Service] END),
    Surgeon2 = max(CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '2' Then [Surgeon] END),
    Proc3 = max(CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '3' Then [Procedure Code (Enctr)] END),
    SvcDate3 = max(Case When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '3' Then [Date of Service] END),
    Surgeon3 = max(CASE When [Encounter Proc Sequence] = '3' Then [Surgeon] END)
    --- etc.
from EncounterProc
where [Date of Service] between '20090101' and '20091231'
    and [Procedure Code (ENCTR)] is not null
group by [Encounter Number], [Encounter Proc Sequence]
```